# Why does this loop generate an error after the first conversion?

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

When I execute the program and I enter C or F and complete the process,
this is the image of what I see:

[image: Screen shot]

I want to hide the line in the red rectangle. This is the code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    float f,c;
    char var;
    int x;

    while(var!='x'){
        printf("x=Ende c=Umrechnung c->f f=Umrechnung f->c:");
        scanf("%c",&var);
        if(var=='c'){
            printf("Grad Celsius =");
            scanf("%f",&c);
            f=(c*1.8)+32;
            printf("%.2f Grad Celsius sind %.2f Grad Fahrenheit\n",c,f);
        }
        else if(var=='f'){
            printf("Grad Fahrenheit =");
            scanf("%f",&f);
            c=(f-32)/1.8;
            printf("%.2f Grad Fahrenheit sind %.2f Grad Celsius\n",f,c);
        }
        else if(var=='x'){
            printf("fertig !! chao\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Ungiltige Umreechnungsart!!\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it works lol thank you

Comment: Aside: `while(var!='x')` note that `var` is an *uninitiliased variable* on the first loop.

Comment: you also have to initialize `var`, otherwise `while(var!='x')` would be undefined behaviour. `printf("Ungiltige Umreechnungsart!!\n");` should be `printf("Ungültige Umrechnungsart!\n");`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case that happens because you are locking for a given character using the `scanf()` and the newline left from the previous call to `scanf()`.

If you call `scanf( %c,&var)` with a space before the `%c` formatting will fix the issue because it will match any white space of any size (including none and the space left from your previous `newline` at the call of `scanf()`.

The function `scanf()` provides no buffer overflow protection, this is particularly a problem when you are reading multiple characters, for example `scanf("%s",&var)` and might become unsafe to use.

A better and safer way to do that is to use `fgets()`:

```
 fgets (value, MAX_VALUE_SIZE, stdin);
```

You can then format the input to whatever you'd like using for example `sscanf()`

Comment: Which buffer are you talking about? And how does the `t` character from `printf` find its way to the input?

Comment: The buffer to were the scanf() stores the matching directives to.

Comment: And how might this buffer overflow? The program has a `char` buffer and a `float` buffer.

Comment: The buffer might overflow if you use for example scanf("%s") where there is no well established end for the directive.

Comment: I was talking about scanf() in general, my bad if that was not clear! I was not stating that this problem had any relation to a buffer overflow. But only that the bad use of scaf() can result in such.

Comment: @WeatherVane I made a mistake it is not t that finds its way to `scanf()` is the `/n`

Comment: So how does this answer the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94496/discussion-between-pecosta-and-weather-vane).

Comment: As it stands, this answer is wrong (`scanf()` is not reading the output from `printf()`, for example).  See also notes in chat.